# Acquiring psd of shield

Tags: stock-images

Does anyone know where I can acquire the stock version (or something similar) of the shield below?

http://www.kobusswartz.co.za/primento/img/logo.png

[image]

Comment: Where have you looked?

Comment: I'm not sure what the image shape is called

Comment: Well, based on your link.. it's a logo. This means that image was most likely created by someone from scratch. You could search for "ribbon" or "Bookmark" to possibly get lucky with something similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Free psd (I imagine that for non-commercial use):

http://www.queness.com/post/9211/30-free-stylish-and-decorative-ribbons-stickers-and-badges-psd-for-web-designers

http://www.thinkthe.me/articles/40-free-stylish-psd-ribbons/

Stock images:

http://www.istockphoto.com/search/text/badge/source/basic#173be3ee

Just look for ribbons or bookmarks. Or google.